# Remove scollbar when no need to scroll

Tags: css, scroll, overflow

I have a `div` with a scollbar as a result of the CSS below.  However, when there is no need to scroll, the bar is still there.  There is no slider/arrows, but an emtpy bar is just there.  Is there a way to only show the bar if the content overflows?  Thanks.

```
#id{
    overflow: -moz-scrollbars-vertical;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use

```
overflow: auto;
```

then overflow will only be displayed if it actually overflows

> auto The behavior of auto isn’t specified in any detail in the CSS2.1
>   specification. In existing implementations it provides scrollbar(s)
>   when necessary, but it doesn’t show scrollbars unless the content
>   overflows the element’s box.

http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/overflow